# submitting form with jquery not working as expected

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to submit a form using jquery after modifying it's action attribute. The action attribute updates fine, but I was expecting the browser location to be the same as the action. But it's not that way. Do you see why?

Here's the form:

```
<form method="GET" class="modForm" action="">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="modSearchValue">
<input type="radio" name="text" value="text" class="text" title="Search">
</form>
```

Here's the jquery:

```
$('.modForm').submit(function(event) {

        var $this = $(this),

        var query = $this.find('.modSearchValue').val(); // Use val() instead of attr('value').
        var locale = window.location;
         if($('.text').is(':checked')){query = '&text='+query;}else{query = '&handle='+query;}
        route = locale+query;
        console.log(route);

        if (query.length >= 1) {
        // Use URI encoding
        var newAction = (route);
        console.log(newAction); // DEBUG
        // Change action attribute
        $this.attr('action', newAction);
        //event.preventDefault();
        } else {
        console.log('Invalid search terms'); // DEBUG
        // Do not submit the form
        event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Here, if the current location is `http://localhost/search` and the search term is 14, the action will be changed to `http://localhost/search/?handle=14` and then submit. But for some reason, it wont.

Comment: `var $this = $(this),` should be `var $this = $(this);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `<form method="POST" class="modForm" action="">` method `POST` for it.......

remove comma `var $this = $(this),` and use `var $this = $(this);`

Comment: remove comma var $this = $(this), and use var $this = $(this)

Comment: Very nice! Thanks, it works. In a funny way though. I'll post another question for that soon.